# How to fill a list view with the contents of List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I've a list

```
    List<String> SampleList=new List<String>();
```

I need to fill a listView with the contents of the list

For example the "SampleList" contains

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
```

The listView should be filled like

```
 S.No         Item

  1             a
  2             b
  3             c
  4             d
```

Now i'm using for loop for this method

like

```
for(int i=0;i<SampleList.Count;i++)
   {
     listView1.Items.Add((i+1).ToString());
     listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(SampleList[i]);
   }
```

is there any other way to do this like data binding ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite like databinding, but you could use VirtualMode and RetrieveVirtualItem

```
listView1.VirtualMode = true;
listView1.RetreiveVirtualItem += new RetrieveVirtualItemEventHandler( this.RetrieveVirtualItem );
listView1.VirtualListSize = SampleList.Count;

private void RetreiveVirtualItem( object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e )
{
     ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem((e.ItemIndex + 1).ToString());
     lvItem.SubItems.Add(SampleList[e.ItemIndex]);
     e.Item = lvItem;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be a `ListView`? `ListBox` is simple:

```
        using (Form form = new Form())
        {
            List<string> strings = new List<string> {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
            form.Controls.Add(new ListBox() {DataSource = strings});
            Application.Run(form);
        }
```

For a richer display, `DataGridView` would also do this, but you need an extra bit of indirection (since it supports multiple columns, it needs a wrapper object per row):

```
        using (Form form = new Form())
        {
            List<string> strings = new List<string> {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
            var indirect = (from s in strings
                            select new {Text = s}).ToList();

            form.Controls.Add(new DataGridView() { DataSource = indirect });
            Application.Run(form);
        }
```

This also gives you opportunity to add in extra data, for example the number:

```
            var indirect = strings.Select((s,i) =>
                new {Index = i + 1, Text = s}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately windows forms ListView doesn't support DataBinding. But if you update the list frequently, maybe you can use INotifyProperty interface.

Comment: @ Mohammadreza : Thank you... please explain  INotifyProperty interface.

Comment: I'm not sure that change notification was a key part of the question.

Comment: @Marc: In my opinion DataBinding is useful if you frequently have to update the underlying component. In this case ListView.

@Pramodh: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I'm very familiar with the interface (which btw does *not* apply in this case; it would be `IBindingList` and `IBindingListView` primarily), but that doesn't make it related to the question...